# Coriolis parameter approximations

Tags: geophysics, oceanography

When solving equations involving the Coriolis parameter $f = 2\Omega\sin{\varphi}$, I often see the $f$-plane (constant) or the $\beta$-plane (Taylor expansion) approximations.

If I'm solving equations on a larger scale in a cartesian coordinate space, would re-projecting the cartesian coordinates onto the sphereoid and re-calculating the Coriolis parameter with the given latitude ($\varphi$) be any less accurate than the $\beta$-plane approximation?

Is the purpose of these approximations to reduce the computational complexity of the model, or somehow to maintain a higher degree of numerical accuracy as opposed to the alternative approach described above?

Comment: Local, linear approximations are analytically solvable. Global, nonliear ones are hardly ever analytically solvable. Re-projecting, i.e. you want to transform between accelerated frames.. sure one can do that, but how would that help in solving the global nonliear problem? You'd end up doing small boosts, to retain linearity, might as well do a numerical solution then...